# How to determine the Android camera angle in an app?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am new to Android, but fairly familiar Java. Well, enough to write with it.

So, I have an idea for a computer vision app. I appreciate that this is a non-trivial problem to solve, but there's no real urgency.

[image: App layout]

So, what I would like to achieve is to figure out where the camera is looking, and eventually if two camera views intersect, given GPS info, compass direction/accelerometer information.

The problem is to work out the angle of the camera on an Android device.

So far, I have bought an Android device and setup Android Development Studio and performed hello world and hello world in OpenCV for Android.

So I think it breaks down like this:

1. Get the GPS location for the device.
2. Get the compass direction from the accelerometers?
3. Get the device orientation from the accelerometers?

Do this for both devices, and calculate collision point of those vectors.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: use the accelerometer (3)

Comment: Awesome. So how? How do i make them real world co-ordinates that relate to another device and thus calculate the intersection point relative to both cameras?

Comment: You're out of luck. GPS will gove you location with expected accuracy of ~10 meters at best. Not good enough to calculate triangles between two devices.

Comment: I'd imagine the GPS approach to not be of any help here too. But the [compass might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974185/android-using-the-hardware-compass).